# How Python’s reduce() works? A combination of cycle on functions and reduce on list (Python, function)

Tags: python, list, iterator, reduce, python-itertools

I'm learning python by my own, so I don't know anybody to ask for help or ask my dumb questions...and I come here for that. Here the problem: I trained some kata on codewars, can't solve one, so I saw the solution and I can't even get how does this code work! Of course, I read about `next()` and `cycle()`, but why they're together there...I just can't get it. Please, could you explain this code, how does it work and why does it work in this way.

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import cycle

def reduce_by_rules(lst, rules):
  rs = cycle(rules)
  return reduce(lambda x, y: next(rs)(x, y), lst)
```

Comment: What is `rules` in that code?

Comment: @Daweo Oi! I really forgot about it. Sorry for that. Rules are all about what I'm supposed to do with elements of the lst. Adding, multiply, divide...something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have two functions. The output of the example below code is `21`.

**Why?**

> At the first, x,y come from first, second elements of `lst`. At continue x comes from return of functions and y comes from the element of `lst`.

1. `x=1`,  `y=2` -> `one(1,2)` -> `1+2+1` -> 4
2. `x=4`,  `y=3` -> `two(4,3)` -> `4+3+2` -> 9
3. `x=9`,  `y=4` -> `one(9,4)` -> `9+4+1` -> 14
4. `x=14`, `y=5` -> `two(14,5)` -> `14+5+2` -> 21 -> return

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import cycle

def one(x,y):
    return x+y+1
def two(x,y):
    return x+y+2


rules = [one, two]
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]

def reduce_by_rules(lst, rules):
    rs = cycle(rules)
    return reduce(lambda x, y: next(rs)(x, y), lst)
    # return two(one(two(one(1,2), 3), 4), 5)


print(reduce_by_rules(lst, rules))
# 21
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helps me a lot! It's so clear now, I can't believe I didn't get earlier^-^

Answer (score 2):

`cycle(rules)` is just a repeating set of functions, for instance:

```
def multiply(x,y):
   return x*y
def divide(x,y):
   return x/y

rules = (multiply, divide)
lst = [range(100)]

def reduce_by_rules(lst, rules):
  rs = cycle(rules) # -> multiply, divide, multiply, divide, ...repeats forever
  # reduce applies the function to each number and return a number reduce(foo, [1,2,3,4]) => foo(foo(foo(1,2),3),4) 
  return reduce(lambda x, y: next(rs)(x, y), lst)

reduce_by_rules(lst, rules)
```

if it helps lemme define my own cycle function:

```
def my_cyle(lst):
   while True:
      for element in lst:
           yield element
```

And my own reduce:

```
def my_reduce(function, lst):
   res = lst[0]
   for e in lst[1:]:
       res = function(res, e)
   return res
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And about your own cycle and reduce functions: it really helps, now I understand the gist of it, I guess^-^